# How to get local IP and display it in TextView?

Tags: android, networking, textview, ip

Many many hours spent to looking for a way (by google and this site), but I can't find a correct a code to write to TextView own ip address of android.

I tried many many codes but no one runs.

What's the correct way to get IP-address of android and put it to TextView?

Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView textView1;
private String tag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    getLocalIpAddress();
    String ip = getLocalIpAddress();
    textView1.setText("IP:"+ip);
}

public String getLocalIpAddress()
{
    try 
    {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();)
        {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();)
            {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) 
                {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        Log.e(tag, ex.toString());
    }
    return "";
}
```

}

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: you are asking 2 different question. You should possibly split it into 2 questions: 1) How to get local IP?; 2) How to display some string in TextView? So, what exactly do you need? Also, it would be great if you post what had you tried already.

Comment: understood. 2 questions: 1) how get local ip address 2) how put local ip address to string? thanks

Comment: So, it should be two different questions :).

Comment: First, `getLocalIpAddress();` line is useless. Second, check what is `R.id.textView1`? Is it declared in `activity_main.xml`? If no, then where it is declared? You could paste it (`activity_main.xml`) as well.

Comment: Also, it seems, you do not assign a value to `tag`... declare it with something like this: `private final String tag = "MainActivity";`, but this is not the main issue, as programs fails on the other line, as you said.

Comment: String ip = getLocalIpAddress(); textView1.setText("IP IS:"+ip);
 
but ip is: fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456%eth0 program doesn't fails. Show hexdecimal value (I think)

Comment: It doesn't fail? :) Sorry I didn't read this at first atempt. So, all is working :) It is not hexademical value, it is IPv6(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)

Answer (score 3):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
WifiManager wim= (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
List<WifiConfiguration> l =  wim.getConfiguredNetworks(); 
WifiConfiguration wc = l.get(0); 
tv.append("\n"+ Formatter.formatIpAddress(wim.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress()));
```

AndroidManifest.xml permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Or you can use this code (without using of Formatter):

```
public String getLocalIpAddress()
{
    try 
    {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();)
        {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();)
            {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) 
                {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        Log.e(tag, ex.toString());
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but also this method doesn't run.

Comment: @PolHallen What exactly doesnt'run? is there any logcat output with error or anything else?

Comment: 11-15 21:31:03.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1849): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @PolHallen specify please full logcat output, or what is 1849 line of unspecified file?

Comment: I can't write whole logcat. What you need 1849 line? Thanks

Comment: @PolHallen you can modify your question and paste logcat there. You have `NullPointerException` - so, something you are trying to use is just `null`. And there is a pointer to the line and source file where the error exists. It is shown somewhere in the bottom part of logcat error log.

Comment: at com.example.netinfo3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42) - Exception at line number 42

Comment: @PolHallen yes, exception occures there. Could you post this line?

Comment: String ip = getLocalIpAddress();
textView1.setText("IP IS:"+ip);

Comment: but ip is: fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456%eth0

Comment: @PolHallen possible, textView1 is null. Split this line in 2 to determine if the problem is in textView1 and double check how you assign a value to textView1, or post it here.

Comment: line 42 is: textView1.setText("IP IS:"+ip);

Comment: @PolHallen or you can paste the full text of `MainActivity.java` (but format it as the code - with 4 leading spaces in beginning of each line)

Comment: Are you initialize variable textView1 or just declare?

Comment: Remove logcat from your question and add code of MainActivity please.

Comment: getLocalIpAddress() returning IPv6 (starting with fe80:....) I need internal IP like : 192.168.1.2 . Any ideas? @ArtyomKiriliyk

Comment: This code without using formatter does not gives a local ip, it just returns 127.0.0.1 and the first method you mentioned, I guess it will work only when WIFI is connected only, not for mobile networks like 3G

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  String IP;
  WifiManager wim= (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
  List<WifiConfiguration> l =  wim.getConfiguredNetworks(); 
  WifiConfiguration wc = l.get(0);
  IP=Formatter.formatIpAddress(wim.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
  tv.setText(IP);
```

Comment: Hey indus, you can simply do tv.setText( Formatter.formatIpAddress(((WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE)).getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress()));

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not complete  , I added few things and it worked for me

Example code ( in Mainactivity )

'''
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private TextView textView1;
private String tag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);
    getLocalIpAddress();
    String ip = getLocalIpAddress();
    textView1.setText("IP:"+ip);
}

public static boolean isNetworkOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
        .getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting());
}

public static String getLocalIpAddress(){
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface
                 .getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf
                     .getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    String sAddr = inetAddress.getHostAddress();

                    return sAddr.toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        return "ERROR Obtaining IP";
    }
    return "No IP Available";
}



public static boolean isActiveVpn(Context mContext) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Network network = cm.getActiveNetwork();
        NetworkCapabilities capabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(network);

        return (capabilities!= null && capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN));
    }
    else {
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_VPN);

        return (info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting());
    }
}
```

}

'''

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).